# How to Hide the data after clicking on Button in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

In the Above Gridview there Are two Buttons 1.Show Data 2.Hide Data. if we click on show data button means it has display data in gridview. if we clicked on hide data it should hide all records in gridview. please anyone tell me how to do with c#

Comment: I think it is working because I can't see the grid....Seriously though, do you have a specific problem with code you have tried?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, as a general rule, you want to post "some" of your markup, and even some code you have - this helps everyone here try to help you.

Since you are new, I'll give you a bit of a break here.

Ok, so assume we have a grid on a page.

And we assume ALSO two buttons on the page. One to show the grid, the other to hide the grid.

So, say our GridView looks like this - the markup (and two buttons).

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        DataKeyNames="ID" 
        CssClass="table" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" >
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName"    />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName"  />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="270" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rating">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbRating" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
                        CssClass="rBut"
                        SelectedValue='<%# Eval("Rating") %>'>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="0">No Rating</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="1">Poor</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="2">Fair</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Good</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="4">Excellent</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Value="5">5 Stars</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View" CssClass="btn"
                        OnClick="cmdView_Click"/>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="cmdShow" runat="server" Text="Show Grid" CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdShow_Click"/>
    <asp:Button ID="cmdHideGird" runat="server" Text="Hide Grid" CssClass="btn"
        style="margin-left:10px" OnClick="cmdHideGird_Click"/>
```

The code to load the grid is this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    public DataTable MyRst(string strSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,
            new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            cmdSQL.Connection.Dispose();
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

And now we have this:

[image]

Now, we have the two buttons. One to show the grid, and the other to hide.

Those two buttons code are this:

```
    protected void cmdShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.Visible = true;
    }

    protected void cmdHideGird_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.Visible = false;
    }
```